# DIfference between a scene and a layer in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-android

can anyone please make me clear about the difference between a Scene & a Layer in COCOS2D. I am bugged up with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddy, it is very simple. Whenever you use COCOS2D, you will be having a class which extends Layer. And which you are going call from Main activity. So for one displayable screen, there can be only one layer. In the class(which extends Layer) can have any number of scenes. You can even set the dimensions for the individual scenes too. But, make sure that, you release the memory immediately after you switch from one scene to another... Enjoy... :)

Comment: This is incorrect. One displayable screen can have multiple layers.